# Perl regex not matching as expected

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I'm trying to compare each word in a list to a string to find matching words, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is some sample code

```
my $sent = "this is a test line";


foreach (@keywords) {      # array of words (contains the word 'test')
  if ($sent =~ /$_/) {
    print "match found";
  }
}
```

---

It seems to work if I manually enter `/test/` instead of `$_`, but I can't enter words manually.

Comment: When I put `@keywords = ('test');` before this and run it, I get `match found`.

Comment: Show how you're setting `@keywords`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I hope you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place in the real program? Here is an example where I have populated `@keywords` with a few items including `test`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sent = "this is a test line";
my @keywords = qw/ a b test d e /;

foreach (@keywords) {
   if ($sent =~ /$_/) {
     print "match found\n";
   }
}
```

**output**

```
match found
match found
match found
```

So your array doesn't contain what you think it does. I would bet that you've read the data from a file or from the keyboard and forgot to remove the newline from the end of each word with `chomp`.

You can do that by simply writing

```
chomp @keywords
```

which will remove a newline (if there is one) from the end of all elements of `@keywords`. To see the real contents of `@keywords`, you can add these lines to your program

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper \@keywords;
```

You will also see that the elements `a` and `e` produce a match as well as `test`, which I guess you don't want. You could add a word boundary metacharacter `\b` before and after the value of `$_`, like this

```
foreach (@keywords) {
   if ( $sent =~ /\b$_\b/ ) {
     print "match found\n";
   }
}
```

but a regular expression's definition of a *word* is very restrictive and allows only alphanumeric characters or an underscore `_`, so `Roger's`, `"essay"`, `99%`, and `nicely-formatted` are not "words" in this sense. Depending on your actual data you may want something different.

Finally, I would write this loop more compactly using `for` instead of `foreach` (they are *identical* in every respect) and the postfixed statement modifier form of `if`, like this

```
for (@keywords) {
   print "match found\n" if $sent =~ /\b$_\b/;
}
```

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I suspect I am too :)